# should i use -f with "hg qimport"

Tags: mercurial, patch

I have a mercurial repository which uses Mercurial queues. Assume the following scenario. I create a patch `firstpatch`, and then pop it.

I make a few changes to the codebase, and create a second patch `secondpatch`. However, when I try to apply `firstpatch` again, I am unsuccessful.

```
$ hg qimport .hg/patches/firstpatch
abort: patch "firstpatch" already exists
```

Then I tried using the -f flag, and in that case

```
$ hg qimport -f .hg/patches/firstpatch
adding firstpatch to series file
```

However, the patch does not show up in the output of the `hg log` command. Somethings off; what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hg qimport` imports a patch that doesn't already exist in the patch queue.  What you want is `hg qpush` to reapply the patch you qpop-ed earlier.

#### Example:

```
C:\db> hg init
C:\db> echo >file1
C:\db> hg ci -Am codebase         # original codebase <contains file1>
adding file1
C:\db> echo >file2
C:\db> hg add
adding file2
C:\db> hg qnew firstpatch         # firstpatch <contains file2>
C:\db> hg qpop                    # remove firstpatch
popping firstpatch
patch queue now empty
C:\db> echo >file3
C:\db> hg add
adding file3
C:\db> hg qnew secondpatch        # secondpatch <contains file3>
C:\db> hg qpush                   # reapply firstpatch
applying firstpatch
now at: firstpatch
C:\db> hg manifest                # all files present
file1
file2
file3
```

Note that a Mercurial queue is managed as a stack.  Creating and removing **firstpatch** allows **secondpatch** to be inserted before it in the queue.  `qpush` then reapplies the next patch in the stack (**firstpatch**).  Use `hg qseries` to see the entire patch list and `hg qapplied` to see only the applied patches.